# Linking Page and client-side password HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

As part as a HTML/JS learning exercise, I am trying to create a very simple user authentication user html forms. I know that it's better to send the input to a server-side PHP but I just want to create a form that :

1. Creates a simple form
2. Creates a submit button that reads a form element
3. Use a javascript function to validate using an onclick (when submitted) attribute if that form item is the required password to access the next page.

Here is my code so far:

My HTML

```
        <div id="login">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            Password: <input id ="pswd" type="password" name="psw" value="">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value ="Submit" onclick = "formValidate()">
        </fieldset>

        </div>

    </div>
```

My JS

```
function formValidate(){
    var validated: false;
    if(document.getElementById("pswd").value == "a"){
        alert("Wow this worked");
        validated = true;
    }
    return validated;
}
```

I just don't seem to have the proper knowledge on how to link html items  to JS functions and vice versa. When I check online it uses forms mainly to do PHP stuff.

Furthermore, if someone can also put me on the right track as to where to look to then send my user to a new page if the password is correct. (In this case, a simple "a")

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Syntax error: `var validated: false;` -> `var validated = false;` If you check your developer console, it would tell you this.

Comment: ...which would throw you: *SyntaxError: missing ; before statement* and *ReferenceError: formValidate is not defined*. This is a typo question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by removing the inline JS (which is generally a bad practice), and adding an event listener.

HTML:

```
<div id="login">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            Password: <input id="pswd" type="password" name="psw" value="">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value ="Submit" id="subbutton">
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("subbutton").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var validated = false;
        if(document.getElementById("pswd").value == "a"){
            alert("Wow this worked");
            validated = true;
        }
        return validated;
});
```

As for your question about directing the user after validation, add this code snippet in the `if` statement, replacing the Google URL with the one you want:

```
window.location.assign("http://google.com");
```

Check out this JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ex3etnpc/

If you need a resource on PHP form handling, look at this tutorial [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Despite a syntax error I still had some unanswered questions so it's greatly appreciated :)

Comment: No problem, happy coding!